# Change the default number of rows to display on one "page"

Tags: datatables

How can I specify the number of rows to display on a single "page" when using DataTables's pagination feature?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**For DataTables version 1.10.5 and newer**, as documented on the [blog post announcing the integration of HTML5 data-* attributes](https://datatables.net/blog/2015-02-12#DataTables-1.10.5), the number of rows to show per page can be specified via the source (HTML) table through the `data-page-length` attribute:

```
<table data-page-length='25'>
     ...
</table>
```

**For DataTables version 1.10 and newer**, as documented at [Reference > Options > pageLength](http://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength), the number of rows to show per page can be specified via the `pageLength` attribute:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "pageLength": 50
});
```

**For DataTables older than version 1.10**, as documented at [DataTables > Usage > Options > iDisplayLength](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayLength), the number of rows to show per page can be specified via the `iDisplayLength` attribute:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": 50
});
```

---

My two cents: use the `data-*` approach. It allows you to construct one dataTable call (that you can use throughout your app) while providing the option to configure how each individual table behaves:

```
<!-- table with embedded custom configurations -->
<table class="apply_dataTable" data-page-length='25'>
     ...
</table>

<!-- table with different embedded custom configurations -->
<table class="apply_dataTable" data-page-length='50' data-order='[[2, "desc"]]'>
     ...
</table>

<!-- one JavaScript call enhances both tables above -->
<script>
    $('table.apply_dataTable').dataTable(); //one invocation of datatables treats each table they way it wants to be
</script>
```

Comment: Now, `data-page-size='25'` will work if `data-page-length='25'` is not working correctly.

Answer (score 26):

Using lengthMenu may help too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
} );
```

} );

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

Comment: While this is helpful, it doesn't answer the question.  The question was not how to modify the default set of values available in the drop down, but how to specify the selected value in that drop down.

Comment: This is the best answer if you are looking to specify a length that is not one of the default lengthMenu entrires.  Otherwise the lengthMenu shows blank as selected. (You will still want to specify the pageLength if you do not want to use the first lengthMenu value as the default)

Answer (score 1):

for 10 records

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({"pageLength": 10});
```

for 50 records

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({"pageLength": 50});
```

for all records

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({"pageLength": -1});
```

Answer (score 0):

using version 1.11 - use the attribute 'data-show'.

Answer (score 0):

We can set attribute using jquery and add up in a common file.

```
$('.dataTablegrid').attr('data-page-length',50);
```

This will apply for all the datatables across the project

Comment: oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
"preDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
  var api = this.api();
  if(settings._iDisplayLength!="50")
  {
    var len = api.page.len(50);
  }
}
});

Answer (score -1):

You Can Write below code in your J-query of Data-Table

```
pageLength: 50,
```

Answer (score -1):

$('#tableID').DataTable(
{
"pageLength": 5
});

Comment: There are **six existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with nearly **one hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.