# Set pagination lenth in DataTables plug-in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I use DataTables plug-in for jQuery and want to set pagination lenth. I.e. I calculated count of page in server side and will draw right amount of buttons on client side. 
Haw can I do it?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the default number of rows to display on one "page"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965934/change-the-default-number-of-rows-to-display-on-one-page)

Comment: @Apha Thank you for answer, but I want to change count of buttons at the bottom of the table. Not count of rows. Because I'll get from the database count of pages  and draw it at the bottom

Comment: maybe there api for paginations from back-end?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display length dynamically by using `fnSettings`:

```
oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();    

var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
oSettings._iDisplayLength = 10;
oTable.fnDraw();
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qeLdbe4/).