# Jquery data-tables - can't manage to set default num of rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using `DataTables 1.10.4` plug-in
to load data into the table suppose 1000 records, and it shows all the **1000**

it also shows the length drop-down (the chosen number is 10)- but it's not effect the table.
If I manually change to any other number from the drop-down it's then effect the table.

I already tried to set it with options:
`pageLength` & `iDisplayLength` 
and it didn't work.

I guess it's not suppose to be like that and it suppose to work.

How can I "force" the length to be change on the table load?

This is th code I am using to init the table:

```
  $("#example-1").dataTable({
            responsive: true,
            aLengthMenu: [
                [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
            ]
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965934/change-the-default-number-of-rows-to-display-on-one-page

Comment: I tried all of this already.. I asked for other solution.

Comment: Show us your code, i.e how you initialise the dataTable - then we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was the Jquery version, I used version 2.1.4.

When I switched to 1.11.3 it worked..

Keep in mind that if your project is using the features that 2.X.X version offers
when you down grade to earlier version, things may "break".