# JQuery DataTables To Show Totals In Footer And Default View

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am attempting to use JQuery Datatables to show the SUM() in footer of my table, and to default sort of 50.  I think my issue stems from my lack of JQuery experience, but I am not sure.  Below is my syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
        buttons: ['csv', 'excel', 'print'],
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        footerCallback: function(row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;
            var intVal = function(i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };
            var totalColumn = function(colNum) {
                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(colNum)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function(a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);
                pageTotal = api
                    .column(colNum, {
                        page: 'current'
                    })
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function(a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);
                $(api.column(colNum).footer()).html(
                    '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
                );
            }
            totalColumn(2);
            totalColumn(3);
            totalColumn(4);
            totalColumn(5);
            totalColumn(6);
            totalColumn(7);
            totalColumn(8);
            totalColumn(9);
        }
    });
});
```

which presents an error of:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sDefaultContent' of undefined
>       at B (datatables.min.js:sourcemap:92)
>       at t.Xb (datatables.min.js:sourcemap:196)
>       at t.iterator (datatables.min.js:sourcemap:175)
>       at t. (datatables.min.js:sourcemap:199)
>       at t. (datatables.min.js:sourcemap:179)
>       at t.data (datatables.min.js:sourcemap:178)
>       at totalColumn (ar-detail-summary:468)
>       at n.fn.init.footerCallback (ar-detail-summary:496)
>       at datatables.min.js:sourcemap:150
>       at Function.map (datatables.min.js:sourcemap:14)

If I remove these lines (or comment them out) then the grid displays (sans the sort and display buttons).

```
    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: ['csv', 'excel', 'print'],
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
```

How should this syntax be edited in order to provide the default sort of 50, have the "print" buttons as well as add sums to the footer?

**Edit**
This is how my table is set-up and being populated form a MS SQL Query results

```
$sql = "SELECT Top 1 * from testdata";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
$numberRows = count($rows);
if ($numberRows >= 1) {
    ?>
    <div id="dvdata">
        <table id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name </th>
                    <th>Total Sale Amt </th>
                    <th>Total Invoice Amt </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $res) {
                print "<tr>";
                print "<td>" . $res->Name . "</td>";
                print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->tsa)) . "</td>";
                print "<td>" . "$" . number_format(round($res->tia)) . "</td>";
                print "</tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<strong>Nothing To Show Here.</strong>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide totalcolumn function and html whic you are using, please

Comment: @amitwadhwani - the totalcolumn function is included in the jquery above, let me edit my post to include the html that generates the table

Comment: Based on your foreach, you have 2 columns with numbers (tsa & tia).  You're executing the totalColumn function for columns that don't exist.  Comment out or remove totalColumn(3) through totalColumn(9) and it will work.

Comment: @c2willi - removing the totalColumn(3) - 9 still presents the same error.

Comment: Also remove those 6 extra <th> entries from your <tfoot>.  See https://jsfiddle.net/kbqf2hp9/.

Comment: @c2willi - add a default sort of 25 to the page and see if it still load properly then.

Comment: I think by default sort you are referring to the iDisplayLength.  This is not really a sort but just how many rows are visible on each page.  Doesn't really impact your footer sum issue. I updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kbqf2hp9/1/ and now it has more rows and iDisplayLength of 5.  Still works.  If you add an additional <th> to the fiddle (like in your example) and run it, you will see the footer logic breaks.

Comment: @c2willi - yes it is the iDisplayLength - interesting your fiddle works but my syntax still does not.  I will toy with it as it appears to be a syntax error since works for you and not for me

Comment: In my case, it is about calculate the column that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, reference to this answer is correct: [Change the default number of rows to display on one "page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965934/change-the-default-number-of-rows-to-display-on-one-page).

Depending on version of DataTables there are three possible solutions listed in answer of stackoverflow question.

I've tried to import you code from above and my DataTable content **showed up**, but in console there was only one error from button **print**. If you will still struggle, add a comment and I will see if anything i can do to it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: each elements works independently.  I.E., I can either have 50 default records & the buttons OR I can have total show.  When I try to add both of them together I have the error above.

Comment: after adding all your code and running it on my datatable, it shows this message: Unknown button type: print <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">, so i really think its a problem with that button print. hope this help!

Comment: I removed the 'print' option and the datatable will now load.  It is showing a default sort of "50" but if I try to change it to "25" it is not updating (or if I change it to "100" it does not update) so something is still going on.  When I check the dev console, I am getting the same error as my OP....it seems that the error is related to the sort function as when I change the sort from 50 to 25 or 50 to 100 - the error is produced in the dev console.

Comment: have you tried to make sort before the data enters in table? Just to clarify if the problem is in sort. Also, DataTables includes order:["number of column (starts with 0)","asc/desc"], which may be of help in this case.

Comment: How would I sort before the data enters the table?

Comment: well, e.g. if you are connected to database and aquiring data from it, or you have array of data, you can sort it with for each loop by specific value and then write it in datatable with **add** method that DataTable API has.